# Android: Control Video quality while invoking intent

Tags: android, video, codec, recorder

I'm invoking Video Recorder as below.

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURED);
```

Is it possible for me to set the recording quality to LOW. is there any final variable I can pass to achieve this task??

Thanks for your time in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I figured out the issue.

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
        intent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 0);
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURED);
```

and the after this size of the video reduced by 80% :) previously 2.5Mb after compression only 0.5Mb

Comment: yeah! but the quality is also reduced 99%.. You get what you pay for.